# State machine implementation in C

Tags: c, oop, switch-statement, state-machine

I have been trying to implement a state machine in C language and I am not
sure whether my implementation is appropriate. I have tried to implement the state diagram in pseudo object manner. So I have declared the public interface of StateMachine "class" in StateMachine.h header file:

```
typedef enum{
  STATE_01,
  STATE_02,
  STATE_03,
  STATE_04
}state_e;

typedef enum{
  NO_EVENT,
  EVENT_01,
  EVENT_02,
  EVENT_03,
  EVENT_04,
  EVENT_05,
  EVENT_06,
  EVENT_07
}event_e;

// state machine instance
typedef struct{
  state_e currState;
}StateMachine;

extern void InitState(StateMachine*);
extern void ProcSTATE_01(StateMachine*, event_e);
extern void ProcSTATE_02(StateMachine*, event_e);
extern void ProcSTATE_03(StateMachine*, event_e);
extern void ProcSTATE_04(StateMachine*, event_e);
extern void ProcEvent(StateMachine*, event_e);
```

The implementation of the StateMachine object "methods" is in the  StateMachine.c module:

```
void InitState(StateMachine *sm)
{
    sm->currState = STATE_01;
}


void ProcSTATE_01(StateMachine *sm, event_e event)
{
  if(event == EVENT_01){
    sm->currState = STATE_02;
  }
}

void ProcSTATE_02(StateMachine *sm, event_e event)
{
  // ...
}

void ProcSTATE_03(StateMachine *sm, event_e event)
{
  // ...
}

void ProcSTATE_04(StateMachine *sm, event_e event)
{
  // ...
}


void ProcEvent(StateMachine *sm, event_e event)
{
    switch(sm->currState){
      case STATE_01:
        ProcSTATE_01(sm, event);
      break;

      case STATE_02:
        ProcSTATE_02(sm, event);
      break;

      case STATE_03:
        ProcSTATE_03(sm, event);
      break;

      case STATE_04:
        ProcSTATE_04(sm, event);
      break;

    }
}
```

The usage of the StateMachine object is following:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    StateMachine app;
    ProcEvent(&app, EVENT_01);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to ask anybody more experienced whether he can see any potential problems which are connected with this implementation. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Having 4 different `ProcSTATE_xx` functions is not the most elegant way.  Pass the xx as parameter and have only one `ProcSTATE` function.

Comment: Nothing here has anything to do with object oriented programming. It is isn't a good or a bad thing by itself. You have an "abstract data type" and it's perfectly OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to think about where your events come from.  Do they only get generated from the state transition handlers themselves, or are they exogenous.  If they are exogenous, then you'll likely want an event loop external to your handler which pulls off events from a queue and injects them in to the appropriate handler (which might enqueue another event to the queue for later handling).  Also, you might want to store your state-event handler functions in an array (indexed on the state number) so you can programmatically call them (instead of having to have a giant switch statement).

Comment: thank you for your reaction. The events in my case come from another part of my program. As far as I understand you in correct manner it shouldn't be problem. But it is necessary to add an event queue where the events are sorted according to their occurence in time. Would it be possible to call the ProcEvent method immediately after evaluation a condition for specific event and so remove the event queue for the beginnig? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last question.  Generally, you would have a state machine, which would include the handlers for all state/event pairs (possibly organized as single handler per state, with a switch/case for events, as you've done), and an event loop that plucks off the events and feeds them in to the appropriate handler.  How exactly this all works will depending on your problem - where do the events come from? Is this multi-threaded (and, thus, you need to worry about locks and race-conditions?) . There's no one answer to "how to build a state machine"...

Answer (score 1):

There is no "correct" way to implement a state machine (like the state table aproach mentioned by Doug), but there is code that can give you direct insights about what is easy to use and what is not.
There is a book by Miro Samek about using hirarchical state machines in c/c++. There he compares the different styles with the state machine style he has developed. And i must say, his style is the one that is most reasonable and readable to me.
Part of the book is also available online at state-machine.com.
Your state machine skeleton in fact is very similar to the state machine part of Miros aproach, his aproach also adds a hirarchical transition possibility, queues per state machine, a system tick mechanism, event recycling, a zero event copying policy and so on. If you look at his web-site you will see that your aproach is a good one that can be extended in many, many ways.